# sub menu based on logged in role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, menu, submenu

I'm trying to learn ASP.NET MVC and have created new project. My first thought was how am I going to provide users means of accessing system areas and functionality.

I am, initially, looking at 2 user roles of User and Administrator. I searched and found the post below on displaying menus based on roles and this is great but I need a method of displaying differing sub menu's for a user and an administrator, for instance an administrator might be able to amend a customers credit limit etc.. but user not. Ideally I would show a sub menu beneath customer menu for CreditLimit that user would not be shown but admin would?

http://techbrij.com/role-based-menu-asp-net-mvc

Is this possible or should I simply create a "Customer" area and show/not show buttons/links on this page based on logged in role?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: definitely possible. pretty slick even. But ultra ambitious for a new developer. and probably not the most efficient. For example, I would use a **partial view with child action method** nested inside the _layout, returning controls looked up by param from a **ViewBag or ActionFilter** (maybe combination) but I wouldn't take a new MVC devloper thru that yet either...

Comment: Yes, for now use separate Areas, or maybe 2 different _layout(s) set within each View (for now) assigning Laout="...". When that works, re-factor the Layout assignment to your ViewStart.cshtml. Then, Finally, now that you've learned a lot, re-factor to **partial view with child action method** within your single _layout bound by a ViewBag/ActionFilter.